# How to update mysql database table each time csv file get uploaded - problem here is I cannot update the "date column"

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

My main problem in my code is I cannot update the "date" from a csv file to mysql database table using php. The line of code  $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]); is the main problem here. I am looking for any alternative query for this specific line of code.

Here is the csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EdMKo-XH7VOXS5HqUh8-m0uWfomcYL5T/view?usp=sharing

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php
//index.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1234", "ml_database");
$message = '';

if(isset($_POST["upload"])) {
    if($_FILES['product_file']['name']) {
        $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['product_file']['name']);
        if(end($filename) == "csv") {
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['product_file']['tmp_name'], "r");
            while($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
                $data_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]);
                $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]); //My Problem
                $births = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[2]);
                $query = "UPDATE my_table 
                            SET date = '$date', 
                                births = '$births', 
                          WHERE data_id = '$data_id'";
                mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            header("location: index.php?updation=1");
        } else {
            $message = '<label class="text-danger">Please Select CSV File only</label>';
        }
    } else {
        $message = '<label class="text-danger">Please Select File</label>';
    }
}

if(isset($_GET["updation"])) {
    $message = '<label class="text-success">Product Updation Done</label>';
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Update Mysql Database through Upload CSV File using PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h2 align="center">Update Mysql Database through Upload CSV File using PHP</a></h2>
   <br />
   <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <p><label>Please Select File(Only CSV Formate)</label>
    <input type="file" name="product_file" /></p>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-info" value="Upload" />
   </form>
   <br />
   <?php echo $message; ?>
   <h3 align="center">Birthss</h3>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Births</th>
     
     </tr>
     <?php
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      echo '
      <tr>
       <td>'.$row["date"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["births"].'</td>
     
      </tr>
      ';
     }
     ?>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The do a proper Parameterized, prepared and bound query and avoid [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) all at the same time. 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: *Here is the csv file* No links - copy 2-3 rows here. *I am looking for any alternative query* Either LOAD DATA into temptable then update (preferred) or CREATE TABLE ENGINE=CSV and update.

Comment: You are also not skipping the **Title** line in the CSV file, could that be most of your problem i.e. failing to convert the string `date` into a date??

Comment: $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]); is the problem because the function mysqli_real_escape_string is not compatible with dates (YYYY-MM-DD). Additionally, I tried removing the variable $date, and it works. The other variable like $data_id and $births which are compatible with this function mysqli_real_escape_string works everytime, and it updates my  MySQL database table from the cv file

Comment: @RiggsFolly yea that is my problem, I cant find any alternative query for the variable $date

Comment: @RiggsFolly with regards to your first comment I have already established the data in my database table, what Im trying to do is how can I update those established data using a csv file through php.

Comment: The query is fine, when converted to be parameterised and prepared - **Did you read the [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) link?? One probelm is you are not reading the TITLE line and throwing it away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to read and discard the Title line in the CSV. Then using a proper, prepared and parameterised query you can update the database correctly. As the date in the .csv file is in the correct format, nothing is needed to be done there, however this may not always be the case with other CSV files, often the date must be reformatted before it will correct store in the table.

```
<?php
//index.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1234", "ml_database");
$message = '';

if(isset($_POST["upload"])) {
    if($_FILES['product_file']['name']) {
        $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['product_file']['name']);

        if(end($filename) == "csv") {
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['product_file']['tmp_name'], "r");
            // read and ignore the TITLE line
            $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

            // prepare the query ONCE
            $query = "UPDATE my_table 
                            SET date = ?, 
                                births = ?
                          WHERE data_id = ?";
            $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);

            // loop over the remaining rows of the csv
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $stmt->bind_param('sss', $data[0],$data[1],$data[2]);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            fclose($handle);
            header("location: index.php?updation=1");
            exit;   // always after a header('Location:.....')
        } else {
            $message = '<label class="text-danger">Please Select CSV File only</label>';
        }
    } else {
        $message = '<label class="text-danger">Please Select File</label>';
    }
}
```

NOTE: I assumed that all 3 columns were text in the bind...

```
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $data[0],$data[1],$data[2]);
                   ^^^
```

If the `date_id` is an integer you can change that to `'ssi'` although the 3 `s`'s will almost definitely work anyway.

**References:**

[fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)
[mysqli_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
[mysqli_bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Thank you so much @RiggsFolly. I'll try it right away

Comment: Sir @RiggsFolly, I kept getting this error sir --
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE data_id = ?' at line 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample_import_csvfile_db\index.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sample_import_csvfile_db\index.php(20): mysqli->prepare('UPDATE my_table...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample_import_csvfile_db\index.php on line 20

Comment: Oh right, missed that error!! There was a comma after `births = ?,` that should be `births = ?` without a comma. Strange that you didnt get the same error from your original code

Comment: Sir @RiggsFolly, sorry for interruption again, The code shows no error, but the problem is the csv file I uploaded, cannot not update my database table.

Comment: Hmmmm, there could be a number of reasons for that. Can you show the schame for that table, Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question. Then can you show what is currently in the table, that data please

Comment: I have put the code in the answer box here sir @RiggsFolly maybe I have arrange it wrong , that is why I cant update my table sir. Can you see it through sir?. Sorry for disturbance sir

Comment: Sir @@RiggsFolly this is my output:
1. This is the current table from database:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oX7Vc6yqcVCGDR5MaNbn9cpci9jmN97K/view?usp=sharing
2. This is the table without an update: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16tzbNASaFJVXm61W9b07q09aRNfUWjup/view?usp=sharing
3. This is the table with an update --after I choose csv file and upload it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RYGro3qlq5qdwTPT2o6wIYs09f2KvZ_n/view?usp=sharing
4. This is the csv file I uploaded to be used to update the table: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11CANghUPNMDiw49gjrxmuaFZjxCYqSz9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, is this working now?

Comment: Not yet sir,  I cant find what is the problem in the code.

Comment: Can you help me again sir @RiggsFolly?